# HDRI appears black in both render and viewport

Tags: 3d-view, hdri

I added a HDRI, but the background is completely black. I tried turning the strength up and down, checked if the thing is equirectangular and properly configured. I also tried to disconnect the compositing nodes and instead just render the original combined image. This came out to still have a black background. Any ideas?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you enable *scene Light* and *Scene World* for the viewport? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnwNZ.png

Comment: yeah I have. Sorry I can't really upload the .blend file, it's 400 MB and my internet isn't exactly great.

Comment: You don't need to upload anything, but explain and show images that show the context and settings. All of your images are so tightly cropped that no one else but you knows what we're looking at.

Comment: you could delete most of the objects to make the file light, and then share it?

Comment: Did you check *View > Perspective/Orthographic*?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is struggling with this issue, I recommend to doublecheck, if the *Viewport Shading* option is set correctly to *Combined*.

In the screenshots above it looks like the current *Viewport Shading* mode was *Glossy Indirect*.

[image: Screenshot: How to change Viewport Shading]

Answer (score 0):

I know this was probably figured out a while ago but I just ran across this problem too. For me it was an issue under color management in the render properties. I had somehow set my gamma amount to zero. Hope this helps for people with this problem in the future.